# Error with accessors on node.js object

Tags: javascript, node.js, properties, contentful, contentful-management

I am interacting with contentful and trying to interact with data using their api using Node.js.

I can show that a certain object has certain properties using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` but when I access them they are undefined. What am I doing wrong?

```
var currentValue = entry.fields;
    console.log("ELEMENT:" + element)
    console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(entry.fields))
    console.log("PROP: " + entry.fields[element])
```

This displays for example:

```
 ELEMENT: averagePledgeBody
[ 'title',
  'subtitle',
  'description',
  'makingThePledgeFact1Heading',
  'makingThePledgeFact1Body',
  'makingThePledgeFact2Heading',
  'makingThePledgeFact2Body',
  'makingThePledgeFact3Heading',
  'makingThePledgeFact3Body',
  'averagePledgeTitle',
  'averagePledgeBody',
  'percentageMinimumPledge',
  'percentageAveragePledge',
  'pledgeAgreementTitle',
  'pledgeAgreementSubtitle',
  'pledgeAgreementButton',
  'callToAction' ]
PROP: undefined
```

Here you can see that the element I am looking for actually exists on the object, yet they all yield undefined when I actually do the lookup. Any ideas?

Comment: what is typeof element?

Comment: the type of is "string"

Comment: I thought of it...just needed to be trimmed... :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was trailing whitespace on the string. Once I trimmed correctly, it worked as expected.